# No module named 'pyPDF2'

Tags: python, import, module, importerror, pypdf

I am using Python 3.5, and it would appear that I've successfully installed PyPDF2. But for some reason, I get an ImportError. Would appreciate any help given.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Imports are case-sensitive. Try `import PyPDF2`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, it worked - I feel like such an idiot.